# How to make webpack load browser versions of submodules as a library author?

Tags: webpack, node-modules, isomorphic-javascript, webpack-2

I'm the author of [arangojs](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs) which is intended to work both in the browser and in node.js but needs different implementations for some of its internals depending on the environment in which it is used (e.g. making HTTP requests and such).

The default configuration of Webpack 1 had `resolve.extensions` set to include `.web.js` and `.webpack.js` with priority over `.js` which allowed targeting webpack specifically by providing browser implementations of submodules using `.web.js` instead of `.js` as the file extension.

But this approach is fragile and the default configuration of Webpack 2 no longer includes these two. Another way would be to explicitly define substitutes in the configuration but again this is fragile and takes conscious effort on the user's end.

Providing two different versions of the same module on npm (e.g. `arangojs-node` and `arangojs-browser`) seems to be the most reliable approach but punishes users writing universal apps because they now have to explicitly install both (and still have to mess with their configuration to make universal code load either of the two as necessary).

As a library author I don't have any direct control over the user's webpack configuration so in practice this means I have to tell users to update their configuration manually.

What's the best approach for dealing with this situation? There don't seem to be any established best practices for library authors in the webpack community.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter users @codemixers and Dan Abramov pointed out to me that both Webpack 1 and 2 have implemented [the `browser` field specification](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec) which can be used to define substitutes. This has also been respected by browserify since practically forever, so it should solve the problem universally.

Specifically this requires adding a new field `browser` to the `package.json` mapping the relative path of each server module to each corresponding browser module:

```
"browser": {
  "./lib/util/btoa.js": "./lib/util/btoa.web.js",
  "./lib/util/bytelength.js": "./lib/util/bytelength.web.js",
  "./lib/util/multipart.js": "./lib/util/multipart.web.js",
  "./lib/util/request.js": "./lib/util/request.web.js"
}
```

I have tested this solution with Webpack 2 and confirmed that the bundle includes the correct files and doesn't try to load the server files and related dependencies, so this seems to be the way to go for third-party libraries like arangojs.

Massive thank you especially to codemix who pointed me to the URL of the actual spec (which can be hard to track down by name alone).